# Low normal form database design on relational RDBS

Tags: database, database-design, rdbms

A friend of mine is creating an application after she designed the database. However, she just put everything in two 1st NF tables, which have a few functional dependencies on non-PK columns. Indeed, she added the PKs after I suggested her. The 3rd+ NF design of her system may require 7 to 15 tables.

I pointed out that there will be a couple of possible update abnormal. However, she said she has stored procedures for insertion and updates so the update abnormal will never happen since she will force the users/applications insert/update the data via the stored procedures.

Is there any other good reason to persuade her to design the system with higher normal form? Or is her solution good enough practically?

Comment: Without knowing the data and the use case there is no way to tell if it's "Good Enough" (TM) practically.

Answer (score 4):

She is probably unskilled and unaware of it.  It has already been demonstrated at large that there is no way to help such people.

She probably thinks that she can get all that code in those SP's right, without making a single mistake.  That is more than just likely a ludicrous overestimation of her own abilities.

I advise you to let her simply make her mistakes.  For YOU, it will save the time of trying and the frustration of not succeeding in getting the message through, and for HER, it will give her the opportunity to learn from her own mistakes (only option left since she's apparently not really willing to learn from other peoples' mistakes), and it will save her the frustration of having to undergo your later coming 'round with that glorious "I told you so.".

But if you really insist on giving it a try, then you might point out to her that :

- her 1NF tables are actually views (materialized views at that) on the 3/BC NF tables that she is willingly not implementing.
- the updates that her end-user probably expects to be doing, are most likely, however, updates to those 7-15 3/BC NF tables.  (I say this because you indicated as her sole reason for the lower NF that she wants to avoid such a "huge" number of tables - the cynicism in "huge" is intentional.)
- but the updates that the DBMS is expecting, are updates to the 1NF tables (which are views).
- Therefore, her problem boils down to "distilling the appropriate updates to 3NF tables from updates that are specified as updates to views on those tables".
- Therefore, getting all her SP code to be correct, is a problem of how to do view updating.
- And guess what, after more than 40 years of research on the relational model, by thousands of researchers whose intellectual abilities exceed hers probably by orders of magnitude, it is exactly this problem of view updating that still stands unsolved ...  (although granted, her problem is not "view updating in general", but "view updating in some given specific situation".  Nonetheless, I very much doubt that she has the skill to spot all the intricacies involved.)

Comment: + 1 The only problem I have with this answer is that letting her learn the hard way translates into someone in the future being handed a mess to maintain at best.  I say treat all software development like you are producing pace makers. Call her out on this horrible design.

Comment: Yes.  I am quite fully aware of that particular problem with my answer, and I sympathise.  However, I disagree that "calling her out" will solve that problem, for the reasons I have indicated (Dunning&Kruger).  The only _real_ solution is to not give the process of building pacemakers into the hands of those who are unable to.  However, that option does not work in our commercial world of "the selling proposition is the only thing that counts".  Google for "PIP breast implants" to see (yet) another illustration of this phenomenon.  There will always be customers prepared to buy just anything.